# RewriteCond simply doesn't work, doesn't check properly if file exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, watermark

I've been trying to solve this for hours now but came up with nothing.

Inside .htaccess, whenever somebody requests an image from a folder of my website, I'm trying to check if a file with the same name exists in another folder; if it does, return that file; if it doesn't, return the file originally requested.

It seems so easy but it simply doesn't work. The .htaccess code is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond /images/blog/watermark/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /images/blog/watermark/$1
```

The "RewriteCond" always returns negative, so the image requested is always loaded as is. If I change it to, like,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

it always returns positive, so it gets the image from the folder I want - except when the image's not there, generating an error, which is exactly what I'm trying to prevent.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

Apparently RewriteCond needs the whole directory structure to check file existence properly.

I added %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} before the path I previously had in my RewriteCond and it worked.

Also, after further reading the documentation, I noticed that the first group is $0 and not $1 when backreferencing from a RewriteRule.

So the final code is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/blog/watermark/$0 -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*) /images/blog/watermark/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong syntax for `RewriteCond`. You probably want to do something more like this:

```
RewriteCond ^/images/blog/watermark/(.*) -f
```

In this case `$1` doesn't actually exist, because `RewriteCond` takes a regular expression, not a replacement string. So, Apache is looking for `/images/blog/watermark/$1` instead of any file inside of `/images/blog/watermark/`.

For reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've seen people using $1 in the RewriteCond clause before trying it, that's why it's there. I guess the way you wrote the clause it just checks if there are files in the folder, while what I want is to check if there is a file with the same name in that folder (hence the $1 reference that I was trying to use).

Even so, changing the clause to this one always returns negative, as if there were no files in the folder :\